# What steps should i follow to find the root cause of a table getting locked in mysql?

Tags: mysql

One of the table in mysql DB is getting locked.
Please let me know the steps that i should follow to find the root cause behind it i.e. who is locking the table and when ?

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that the table is locked - does it appear in the results of:

```
mysql> SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use;
```

If it is currently locked, from the command line, run:

```
# mysqladmin debug -u <user> -p
```

(`<user>` is most likely `root`, depending on your set-up)

Now check your error log (this is inside the data directory by default, find the location by checking your `my.cnf` file). You should find details of the process doing the locking.

The relevant bit of the output looks like:

```
Current locks:
lock: 0x7f759da38e90: write
write     : 0x7f759da97a00 (54:12);
```

From within the database (with a user with the `SUPER` privilege) run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to find out which session the logs are referring to. In the example above, you want the process ID `54` (identified by the `(54:12)`).

Comment: After running SHOW PROCESSLIST, i got few enteries like following: 27592  admin 192.236.173.48:44893  AppDB Query  2287  Locked  UPDATE FILE_VERSION SET STATUS = 'LATEST' WHERE FILE_VERSION_ID = 710406

Comment: Can you identify where that query is coming from (using the data in that table like `User` and `Host`)? Is it likely to be what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for helping. I did not find anything in these tables which can help me finding who locked the table.

Comment: INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 33 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 7, signal count 7
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 60, OS waits 3
RW-shared spins 8, OS waits 4; RW-excl spins 0, OS waits 0

Comment: ------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 28506
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 23761 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 17
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, OS thread id 25
MySQL thread id 28507, query id 4301662 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 28500, not started, OS thread id 21
MySQL thread id 19407, query id 4296397 10.86.169.105 gecareers
---TRANSACTION 0 28498, not started, OS thread id 16
MySQL thread id 19410, query id 4299236 10.86.169.106 gecareers

Comment: Did you run the `mysqladmin debug` command to get the info dumped to the error log after verifying that the table is locked? Also, it might be best to put some of your data in the original question body rather than comments - you can get nicer formatting that way.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your help. I was able to find the query which is taking really long to execute and hence locking other update queries.